# Why is the work done by the system equal $p_{\rm external} (V_{\rm final} - V_{\rm initial})$?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, ideal-gas, volume

Please See this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j_6JxoL8qD4

Firstly, at 1:13 in the video, is the work done here by the system or on the system?

Secondly, are V final(s) in both cases equal? Are both cases adiabatic?

Answer (score 1):

The irreversible work in the rectangle is the work done **by** the gas **on** its surroundings (the piston/atmosphere).  In the two cases, the final volumes are supposed to be equal, and the implicit assumption is that both systems are comparable and adiabatic.

In both reversible and irreversible expansions, the work done by the system on its surroundings is the integral of $P_{B}dV$, where $P_{B}$ is the force per unit area at the boundary interface between the system and its surroundings (in this case the inside face of the piston). In the case of a reversible process, the gas pressure is uniform throughout the system, and the force per unit area exerted by the gas at the interface is equal to the value calculated from the ideal gas law, based on the (uniform) temperature and volume of the system.

However, in an irreversible process (involving a very rapid expansion of the gas), the gas pressure and temperature vary with spatial position within the system (the cylinder), so the force per unit area exerted by the gas at the piston face is not equal to the pressure elsewhere within the system or even to the average gas pressure.  So we can't apply the ideal gas law to calculate the force per unit area at the piston face.  The ideal gas law is only valid globally under thermodynamic equilibrium conditions.  In addition to all this, because the gas is deforming rapidly, there are viscous forces within the gas which affect the force per unit area at the piston face.  These viscous forces are determined, not by the gas volume, but by the rate at which the gas volume is changing.  So, for an irreversible expansion, getting the force per unit area at the piston face to calculate the work done on the surroundings is problematic, to say the least.  One way we have to get around this is by manually (externally) imposing the force at the piston.  That is what is done in the video, where the pressure at the piston face is constrained to match the atmospheric pressure during the irreversible expansion.

Comment: if the works done by the gas on its surrounding are different in two case, the  internal energies of gas at final state will be different (because $\delta e = \delta w +\delta q$),in turn the temperature of gas will be diferent. Pressures of gas at final state are equal atmosphreric pressure, so the volume will be different. What do you think about this?

Comment: It think that your assessment is totally correct.  The final temperature and volume in the irreversible expansion will be higher than in the reversible expansion.  For a complete analysis of this exact problem, see Example 3 in the following reference:  https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/grandpa-chets-entropy-recipe/